# How to make a wpf user control containing several user controls

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I have created a WPF User control library. It has by default 1 user control in it. I added two more user controls on it. Added next back button to everycontrol. Now I am stuck here. What should I do to navigate from one user control to another? Can I do that in MVVM pattern? if yes then how?

Comment: u want create a library browser for your controls?

Comment: yes. this library provides some functionality to the main program. like getting some input and doing some actions after that. This functionality keep on changing. So i want that instead of dilvering all new files i instead give a dll file which can be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading [Telerik trial pack](http://www.telerik.com/download-trial-file.aspx?pid=601), they have a demo app (with source) that allows to browse their control. An once you have that demo app you can switch the user control dll in background when an update occurs.

Comment: problem is not updating dll. problem is how to navigate in different views inside a dll.

Comment: have u downloaded the trial and seen the demo project?

Comment: no. but as your comment say "you can switch the user control dll in background when an update occurs" from this i get that you are talking about updading dll file.